# Why isn't my FOR loop in R working? While any single step works

Tags: r

```
list<-c("a2012","a2013")

a2012<-c("al,","al,rb,","cu,pvc,")
a2013<-c("ab,al,","al,cu,","pvc,al,")

sum(str_count(a2012,"al,")==1)
[1] 2
sum(str_count(a2013,"al,")==1)
[1] 3

output <- vector("integer")
for(i in seq_along(list))
{
output[[i]]<-sum(str_count(list[[i]],"al,")==1)
}
output
[1] 0 0
```

This is the whole process. I'm pretty much a noob.

I don't know why this happens. Please help

Comment: Do `list <- list(a2012, a2013)`.

Comment: you appear to be trying to use `list[[i]]` to extract the entry from the list, then use that to take the place of a variable name, which is not really the right approach.  I'll have a go at clarifying in an answer.  Also note that you're using the `stringr` library (I assume) - this should be included in your question.

Comment: Because you are calling a character value instead of a variable. You can use `get` to solve it. `output[[i]]<-sum(str_count(get(list[[i]]),"al,")==1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a2012<-c("al,","al,rb,","cu,pvc,")
a2013<-c("ab,al,","al,cu,","pvc,al,")

mylist <- list("a2012" = a2012,
               "a2013" = a2013)

output <- vector("integer")
for(i in seq_along(mylist))
    {
      output[[i]]<-sum(str_count(mylist[[i]],"al,")==1)
    }

> output
[1] 2 3

> mylist
$a2012
[1] "al,"     "al,rb,"  "cu,pvc,"

$a2013
[1] "ab,al,"  "al,cu,"  "pvc,al,"
```

The main thing is that your list doesn't need to contain names and then refer to variables by those names - it can just contain the vectors themselves.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! You solved my problem for tonight.